Is this a valid definition of tangent space?
Given a smooth manifold $M$ and a point $p\in M$, I wonder if the tangent space of $M$ at $p$, denoted $T_pM$, can be defined in the following way. First define tangent space for $\mathbb{R}^n$ in any reasonable way. Consider the collection of all charts $\varphi_i:M\supseteq U_i\rightarrow V_i\subseteq
\mathbb{R}^n,\ i\in I$ such that $p\in U_i$. The vector spaces $T_{\varphi_i(p)}\mathbb{R}^n$ form a groupoid with the property that there is a unique morphism from $T_{\varphi_i(p)}\mathbb{R}^n$ to $T_{\varphi_j(p)}\mathbb{R}^n$, namely the map induced by the homeomorphism $\varphi_j\circ\varphi_i^{-1}$. Thus these vector spaces are canonically identified, which we define to be $T_pM$. For some reason I like this definition better than the standard definitions using derivation or "directions" of smooth curves.
Is there any text that uses something close to this definition? And does "groupoid with unique morphisms between two objects" have a name?

It's called a contractible groupoid: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/contractible+type In category theory this is in some sense the correct generalization of something being unique, e.g. this is the notion of uniqueness that any object defined by a universal property possesses.

Anyway, I think this definition can be made to work but it seems to make defining, for example, the total space of the tangent bundle awkward, since you need to choose a bunch of charts. Using derivations and so forth produces an honest vector space on the nose so there's no need to make such a choice (I think).

Sounds similar to definition 2.8 on the nLab.

@QiaochuYuan What do you mean by choosing a bunch of charts? Once we have defined the tangent space at each point, can't we just glue them together to get the tangent bundle as usual? The topology of $TU_i$ is induced by the topology on $T\varphi_i(U_i)$, which doesn't depend on the choice of $i$.

This is nitpicky (and similar issues arise and are routinely ignored in category theory) but strictly speaking, to write down the total space of the tangent bundle you first of all have to write down its underlying set. What set is this? Your construction does not produce a set but a contractible groupoid of sets. Strictly speaking to get a set on the nose you have to choose charts. Of course the result doesn't depend on this choice but it's an awkward feature of set-theoretic foundations that you still have to write down an underlying set.

@QiaochuYuan If I have a contractible groupoid of vector spaces, can't I "identify them" by defining a vector space whose elements are equivalence classes of elements of those vector spaces?

Honestly I haven't thought about it! That seems like it could work but I haven't seen it before. I guess equivalently this is the colimit of the corresponding diagram of vector spaces. Interesting!
